# is sizeof() likely to be optimized away?

Tags: c++

I have this struct:

```
struct KVP {
    uint32_t KeyLenB;
    uint32_t ValLenB;

    void Set (char* pKey, uint32_t KeyLenB, char* pVal, uint32_t ValLenB) {
        this->KeyLenB = KeyLenB;
        this->ValLenB = ValLenB;
        memcpy(this + sizeof(KVP), pKey, KeyLenB);
        memcpy(this + sizeof(KVP) + KeyLenB, pVal, ValLenB);
    }

snip

};
```

those go into a preallocated chunk of memory. The alternative was to add another member after the length fields and just reference that but sizeof(KVP) returning just the size of the length fields works out neater in rest of the code.

So anyways, since this function is going to be called a lot, I want to know if "this+sizeof(this)" would be any slower than giving the pointer to the potential 3rd member?

Yes, I'm aware that this steams of unnecessary optimization and yadayada but this is the 3rd time I'm rebuilding this piece of software, its my baby and I don't care if it never sees the light of day as long as its perfect.

Comment: `this + sizeof(KVP)` does not do what you think.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: You know how dangerous this looks?

Comment: "perfect" is not an adjective that belongs anywhere near this code (unless "not" is also present)

Comment: this goes into a mmf, dynamic allocation is out, how would you suggest I put variable size data in there then? I keep track of the position/size of each object manually since I don't really have a choice.

Comment: `this + n` produces a pointer to the item at index `n` in an array of `KVP`. For the first address computation you could use `this + 1`. For the second you'd need to be more clever.

Comment: thats a good point and i totally missed that, &this[1] should do it?

Comment: If you want to update 2 objects, then pass a pointer to the first object and increment it to get the second object. Hacking on the `this` parameter to find the second object, which may or may not exist, is asking for trouble. Your code may also be making assumptions about endianness.

Comment: @NeilKirk I'm not trying to get the next object, its still the same object, just the variable length data is kept right after the "official" class. When I place the next object it will be after this objects data(both inside and outside) ends. Endianness shouldn't be a problem since this is the only thing that reads/writes to it, whichever way it goes in it comes back out too.

Comment: "I don't care if it never sees the light of day as long as its perfect." — If you try to make it perfect then it will indeed never see the light of day. Aim for "really good" instead if the light of day is a priority.

Comment: There is nothing to 'optimize away'. It's a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`sizeof` is not a function, it is an operator, and it is evaluated at compile-time before any of your code runs. Therefore, using `sizeof` incurs zero cost at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` is always evaluated at compile time. It costs exactly as much as any other constant, including the offset of another member.

So yes, it will definitely be optimised away.

Answer (score 0):

In C, this is common/doable.  In C++, KVP could never be inherited from.  But, Set can't be a member function although it could be a constructor and/or class specific new operator because the constructor/new has to allocate the extra space:  KeyLenB + 1 + ValLenB + 1 before Set is called.

So, if you really want to do this as written, consider putting it in a .c file [with appropriate "extern C" stuff] so that you can use malloc and don't collide with constructors, etc.  That's probably easier than putting it in a .cpp and disabling all the standard constructors/destructors, etc.

But, you may have to take your variable length pain another way.  Consider splitting KVP into KVP and a "string" struct.  You've got two options:

```
struct mystring {
    uint32_t str_len;
    char str_data[0];
};

struct KVP {
    mystring *kvp_key;
    mystring *kvp_val;
};

mystring *
newstring(char *val)
{
    struct mystring *str;
    uint32_t len;

    len = strlen(val);
    str->str_len = len;

    str = malloc(sizeof(struct mystring) + len + 1);
    memcpy(str->str_data,val,len + 1);

    return str;
}
```

The above newstring is a similar approach to what your Set is trying to do.  But consider the alternative:

```
struct mystring {
    uint32_t str_len;
    char *str_data;
};

struct KVP {
    mystring kvp_key;
    mystring kvp_val;
};

mystring *
newstring(char *val)
{
    struct mystring *str;
    uint32_t len;

    len = strlen(val);
    str->str_len = len;

    str->_str_data = malloc(sizeof(struct mystring) + len + 1);
    memcpy(str->str_data,val,len + 1);

    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the cuff code, not compiled:

```
class Key_and_value
{
private:
    int32_t  key_length_;
    int32_t  value_length_;
    char     data_[1];

public:
    Key_and_value(
        char const* const  key,
        int32_t const      key_length,
        char const* const  value,
        int32_t            value_length
        )
        : key_length_( key_length )
        , value_length( value_length )
    {
        memcpy( data, key, key_length );
        memcpy( data + key_length, value, value_length );
    }
};
```

A key notion here is to use a constructor. With a setter function you would be able to change the memory footprint size of the object, possibly after some other such variable length object had been placed after it.

To construct the object in pre-existing storage you can include the `<new>` header and use placement new, like `::new( my_storage ) Key_and_value( blah... )`. But be sure that the storage starts on a suitably aligned address. If necessary read up on alignment.

There is no `sizeof` in this code so the question about that is moot. But anyway, in C++ that's a compile time expression. It has roughly no runtime cost.

As others have already remarked, it's much more important to create correct code than to create merely fast code. It doesn't matter if the code is very fast if it's also very incorrect (indeed, if the code can be arbitrarily incorrect then it can also be arbitrarily fast, doing nothing). So the general advice is: don't do this, at least not at first, and if or when you do feel that some optimization could be just what's needed, then first **MEASURE**.

Comment: It has *exactly* no runtime cost.

Comment: @EJP: No. It *can* have no runtime cost by being optimized away. But in the general case a use of `sizeof` produces one or more byte of data in the machine code. That increases the machine code size, which can affect caching and prediction, and so on. In practice it's negligible, but a statement that it's exactly zero, is just wrong.